# call a js function based on the argument passed

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm trying to call a js function within another one, but use the argument to specify the function. ie depending on the argument passed, it will call a different function

```
   function toggle(n){
        if (sessionStorage['toggle'+n]== 0){

            check+n();      
        }
        else 
    }
```

So, for example, if the argument 'Balloons' was passed as *n*, then it will call the function checkBalloons(). `"check+n();"` is not currently working here. Sorry for my lack of simple js syntax!

Comment: Consider if it would be better to make a generic `check` that takes parameter `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is defined in the global scope (browser) you can do:

```
window["check"+n]();
```

or some tenants like Node.js you would access it from global object.

```
global["check"+n]();
```

if it is a part of some other object then you would do the same.

```
 obj["check"+n]();
```

Functions and properties defined on an object can be accessed using `[]` convention as well. i.e `obj["propFuncName"]` will give you reference to it, so in case of methods you add `()` to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I will have to read up on the scope of functions as I'm not sure which to use. Thanks for help, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the function is global, you would do this:

```
window["check" + n]();
```

or, you could put your function in an object like so:

```
myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.checkSomething = function(){ /* ... */ }

// call it like this:
myNamespace["check" + n]();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers thus far are correct, but lack explanation.

In JavaScript, you cannot call a function by name when that name is a string. What you *can* do is *retrieve a value from an object* by name, and if that value happens to be a function, you can then call it. For example:

```javascript
var myObject = {};
myObject.myFunction = function() { alert('test!'); };

// Get the property on `myObject` called `myFunction`
var theFunctionLookup = myObject['myFunction'];
// Since that property was a function, you can call it!
theFunctionLookup();
```

In the browser, functions that are defined in the global scope are attached to the `window` object. For example, this works:

```javascript
function myFunction() { alert('test'); }
var theFunctionLookup = window['myFunction'];
theFunctionLookup();
```

You can shorten the last two lines into one:

```javascript
function myFunction() { alert('test'); }
// Look up and call the function in one line.
window['myFunction']();
```

For the same reasons, you can use a dynamically-calculated string to look up functions.

```javascript
function checkBalloon() {
  alert('checking balloon');
}

function toggle(n){
  if (sessionStorage['toggle'+n]== 0){
    window['check' + n]();
    check+n();      
  }
}

toggle('Balloon');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do this way:

```
    if (sessionStorage['toggle'+n]== 0){

        window["check" + n]();
    }
```

will work

Comment: ok.... out of interest, what's the window part? I thought I was just not writing the syntax correctly?

Comment: you're accessing your method as a object property. Every global variable or function set in your code (not set into another function) will be set in your window object.

Comment: call a function only typing "check()", is the same thing that you call "window.check()", or "window["check"]()"